# Add the values to the Option box & Check box

Tags: excel, vba

May I know, how to make the option box and checkbox checked as in the list box? Let say, if the data is yes so that the option box will automatically be checked and another one if the choose Whatsapp and email it will automatically be checked at the WhatsApp and email.

The column from Method is starting from column C9 and for Participation at column D9.

FYI,

> Emp 2 - Yes Emp 3 - No Emp 8 - Whatsapp  Emp 9 - Phone Call  Emp 10 -
>   Facebook  Emp 11 -Email  Emp 12 - SMS

[image]

And here is the coding that I already try

```
Private Sub lstEmployee_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'dim the variables
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

'find the selected list item
i = Me.lstEmployee.ListIndex

'add the values to the text boxes
Dim methodsOfCommunication() As String

Me.Emp1.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(0, i)
Select Case Me.lstEmployee.Column(2, i)
    Case "Yes"
        Emp2.Value = True
        Emp3.Value = False
    Case "No"
        Emp2.Value = False
        Emp3.Value = True
End Select

' Reset Methods of Communication checkboxes.
Emp8.Value = False
Emp9.Value = False
Emp10.Value = False
Emp11.Value = False
Emp12.Value = False
' Set Methods of Communication checkboxes.
methodsOfCommunication = Split(Me.lstEmployee.Column(1, i), ", ")
For i = LBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1) To UBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1)
    Select Case methodsOfCommunication(i)
        Case "Whatsapp"
            Emp8.Value = True
        Case "Phone Call"
            Emp9.Value = True
        Case "Facebook"
            Emp10.Value = True
        Case "Email"
            Emp11.Value = True
        Case "SMS"
            Emp12.Value = True
    End Select
Next

Me.Emp4.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(3, i)
Me.Emp5.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(4, i)
Me.Emp6.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(5, i)
Me.Emp7.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(6, i)
Me.Emp13.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(7, i)
Me.Emp14.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(8, i)
Me.Emp15.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(9, i)

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not see the option box and checkbox in the listbox?

Comment: From the list box, I want to add the value into the opt/checkbox. @SiddharthRout

Comment: What do the following variables represent: Emp2, Emp3, and Emp8 through Emp12? Are they the option and checkbox controls on the form? If yes, then the code is taking the values from those controls, and using them to set the values in the listbox, which is the opposite of what you said you want. Am I correct that the textbox and combobox controls on the form are correctly pulling data from the listbox? Can you post a snippet of code showing how a textbox or combobox is being set?

Comment: @KenLove I already update the question. Actually what I want to do is - I want to add value in the list box to the opt/checkbox.

Comment: I don't know if there are any hidden columns or not. What is the column number for the rolled-up "Method of Communication", and what is the column number for the "Participation in BTS Fund"?

Comment: Method starting at column C9 and Participation in BTS Fund starting at column D9 :) There is no hidden column.

Comment: Sorry I meant in the Listbox. What is the column number in the Listbox for the rolled-up "Method of Communication", and what is the column number in the Listbox for the "Participation in BTS Fund"? For example, is it `Me.lstEmployee.Column(3, i)` and `Me.lstEmployee.Column(4, i)`?

Comment: @KenLove for method it is Me.lstEmployee.Column(1, i) and for Participation it is Me.lstEmployee.Column(2, i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim methodsOfCommunication() As String
Dim i As Integer

Me.Emp1.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(0, i)
Select Case Me.lstEmployee.Column(2, i)
    Case "Yes"
        Me.Emp2.Value = True
        Me.Emp3.Value = False
    Case "No"
        Me.Emp2.Value = False
        Me.Emp3.Value = True
End Select

' Reset Methods of Communication checkboxes.
Me.Emp8.Value = False
Me.Emp9.Value = False
Me.Emp10.Value = False
Me.Emp11.Value = False
Me.Emp12.Value = False
' Set Methods of Communication checkboxes.
methodsOfCommunication = Split(Me.lstEmployee.Column(1, i), ", ")
For i = LBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1) To UBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1)
    Select Case methodsOfCommunication(i)
        Case "Whatsapp"
            Me.Emp8.Value = True
        Case "Phone Call"
            Me.Emp9.Value = True
        Case "Facebook"
            Me.Emp10.Value = True
        Case "Email"
            Me.Emp11.Value = True
        Case "SMS"
            Me.Emp12.Value = True
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Ken :)

Comment: There is an error when I try to edit. I will show the picture later,

Comment: But before that, may I ask you - if Emp 1 is at the first column in the list box - it should be Me.lstEmployee.Column(0, i) or Me.lstEmployee.Column(1, i)

Comment: When I double click, only name it will add the value in text box. And some of it, when i double click it will show the previous data even though the name already change,

Comment: The Listbox.Column property uses a zero-based index, so the first column is 0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.column

Comment: Orait, then its right, But why when I add the value it does not show exactly as in the text box?

Comment: I already update my question. I put the whole coding. Hope you can check it.

Comment: I looked at the whole procedure, but I'm not sure I understand your question. When you add a value where? Which textbox is having a problem? Is there other code that I can't see that you are referring to?

Comment: Are you "double clicking" the Listbox? This procedure handles double click events, not single click events. Could it be that you have a separate event handler for single "click" events, which is updating the name field?

Comment: yes, I double click. but, it will appear like the picture in the comment above. i don't know what is the error :(

Comment: I forgot to add "Me." to some of the controls. I revised the answer.

Comment: Still the same :( The data that come out in the box is just random from the list box :(

Comment: Can you comment out `On Error Resume Next` to see if there is an error occurring and where?

Comment: Are you sure the "Participation in BTS Fund" and "Method of Communication" controls are not being updated when you double-click different rows in the Listbox? For example, when you double-click "Aira" do the "Whatsapp" and "Phone Call" checkboxes become checked?

Comment: I just realise it will happen at "Amount to be collected", "Acct. Mgr", "Phone" and "Email".

Comment: Ok I can research it some more. If you would kindly accept the answer since it appears to have answered the original scope of your question, that would be helpful.

Comment: Orait, thank you for your time. Hopefully you can help me since i need to submit in less than one hour :(

Comment: I think it has to do with how the "Amount to be collected" and "Acct. Mgr" ComboBoxes are setup. They might be setup using a hidden numeric value, and the code is trying to set it with a text value from the ListBox. Or the ComboBoxes might require an exact matching value. I think you will need more logic to set those ComboBoxes.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKjaf.jpg Oh, now i understand. As you can see in the picture, why I key in RM20 but in the formula it will appear 20?

Comment: I already change all of it as General. But still the error is same :(